# How can I fake dependent types in C++ for non-constant, and local data?

Tags: c++, templates, types

Below is some code which almost works. What I want to do is create memory pools which autodelete their contents on destruction (it's okay if it only works for plain old data), and have a compile time guarentee that the pool must always survive longer than the pointers to it's contents do. In my attempt to accomplish this, I made the pointers have the pool which they point to a part of their type. My strategy seems as if it should work but C++ only allows constant, or global data as template parameters which stops me programming how I want. For example, in the code below the memory pool must be a global value. How can I fake dependent types in C++ for non-constant, and local data?

Here's the code, and a simple example showing how to use it. I apologize for not dealing with alignment issues, but this is just a simple proof of concept anyways.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>


class pool;

template<typename T, pool& H>
class reference;


class pool {
private:
 pool(const pool&);
 pool& operator=(const pool&);

 const pool* operator&() const;
 pool* operator&();


 size_t size; 
 void *storage;

 size_t tag;

public:
 pool() : size(0), storage(0) { }
 ~pool() { free(storage); }

template<typename, pool&> friend class reference;
template<typename T, pool& H> friend reference<T, H> allocate();
};


template<typename T, pool &H>
class reference {
private:
 reference();

 size_t index;

 reference(size_t _index) : index(_index) { }

public:
 friend class pool;

 void set(const T& rvalue) const {
  *((T*)&((char*)H.storage)[index]) = rvalue;
 }

 T operator*() const {
  return *((T*)&((char*)H.storage)[index]);
 }

 reference<T, H>& operator++() {
  index += sizeof(T);
  return *this;
 }

template<typename U, pool& I> friend reference<U, I> allocate();
};

// TODO: Add in alignment stuff
template<typename T, pool& H>
reference<T, H> allocate() {
 const size_t old_size = H.size;

 H.size += sizeof(T);
 H.storage = realloc(H.storage, H.size);

 return reference<T, H>(old_size);
}


template<pool& H>
reference<char, H> get_line() {
 const reference<char, H> start = allocate<char, H>();
 reference<char, H> end = start;

 char input;

 for (;;) {
  input = std::cin.get();

  if ('\n' == input) {
   break;
  }

  end.set(input);
  end = allocate<char, H>();
 }

 end.set('\0');

 return start; 
}

template<pool &H>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, reference<char, H> start) {
 for (; *start != '\0'; ++start)
  std::cout.put(*start);

 return out;
}


pool input_pool;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

 std::cout << "What is your name?" << std::endl;

 const reference<char, input_pool> input_string = get_line<input_pool>();

 std::cout << "Hello " << input_string << "!" << std::endl;


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would the compile-time guarantee work?  Would you get a compile error if a function tried to return a reference<> to a local pool?

Comment: 'In case what you want is compile-time errors, you can have solutions based on std::enable_if<> function. Is this what you're expecting?

Comment: @VaughnCato What would the type of a function returning a reference to a local pool be? Because the function can't be typed it wouldn't be able to be created, and therefore giving strong guarantees.

Comment: One possibility is to make the references be non-copyable.  You then wouldn't be able to return one.

Comment: @VaugnCato But your approach loses some type safety or sacrifices memory. References will be able to index into the wrong pool, or will have to carry a pointer to it around with them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps you or not, but the following compiles:

```
class pool {};

template<pool& H>
class reference {
};

struct pools {
  static pool hopefullyStaysInCache;
  static pool hopefullyStaysInMemory;
  static pool canSwapOutToDisk;
};

main(){
  reference<pools::hopefullyStaysInMemory> y;
}
```

You can be sure the pools won't be deleted too soon because they can never be deleted.  A pool's storage can be deleted, making it small enough that you probably don't mind keeping it around, and you can make the deletion happen automatically when the last reference in the pool is destroyed.